# Do md5sum on files inside a directory and check if there are identical files

Tags: bash, shell, md5, md5sum

I'm studying shell script and there is an exercise asking to calculate the md5 hash of all files of a folder. It also asks to, in case there's two files with the same hash, print their names in the terminal. My code can do that, but once it finds a match, it's printed twice. I can't figure out how to exclude the first file name from the next iterations.
Another thing: It's forbidden to create any temporary files to help with the task.

```
#!/bin/bash

ifs=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

echo "Verifying the files inside the directory..."

for file1 in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | cut -d "/" -f2); do
  md51=$(md5sum $file1  | cut -d " " -f1)
  for file2 in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | cut -d "/" -f2 | grep -v "$file1"); do
    md52=$(md5sum $file2 | cut -d " " -f1)
    if [ "$md51" == "$md52" ]; then
      echo "Files $file1 e $file2 are the same."
    fi
  done
done
```

I also would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do this task.

Comment: Of course there is. What if you print out every file **md5sum**, sort them and find two o more consecutive md5sums? `find ··· | xargs md5sum | sort | uniq ···`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
mapfile -t list < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort)
mapfile -t dups < <(printf "%s\n" "${list[@]}" | grep -f <(printf "^%s\n" "${list[@]}" | sed 's/ .*//' | sort | uniq -d))

# here the array dups containing the all duplicates along with their md5sum
# you can print the array using a simple
printf "%s\n" "${dups[@]}"
```

and will get output like:

```
3b0332e02daabf31651a5a0d81ba830a  ./f2.txt
3b0332e02daabf31651a5a0d81ba830a  ./fff
c9eb23b681c34412f6e6f3168e3990a4  ./both.txt
c9eb23b681c34412f6e6f3168e3990a4  ./f_out
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./aa
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./abc def.xxx
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./dudu
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./start
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./xx_yy
```

The following addition is just for a fancier printout

```
echo "duplicates:"
while read md5; do
        echo "$md5"
        printf "%s\n" "${dups[@]}" | grep "$md5" | sed 's/[^ ]* /  /'
done < <(printf "%s\n" "${dups[@]}" | sed 's/ .*//' | sort -u)
```

will print something like:

```
3b0332e02daabf31651a5a0d81ba830a
   ./f2.txt
   ./fff
c9eb23b681c34412f6e6f3168e3990a4
   ./both.txt
   ./f_out
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
   ./aa
   ./abc def.xxx
   ./dudu
   ./start
   ./xx_yy
```

Warning: will work only if the filenames doesn't contains the `\n` (newline) character. Modifying the script be general needs bash `4.4+`, where the `mapfile` knows the `-d` parameter.

Comment: It's forbidden to create any temporary files to help with the task.

Comment: @cmks do you know that the `readarray` is just an another name for the `mapfile`? try: `help readarray` and `help mapfile`... No temporary files used in the solution - maybe you need just more careful reading. ;)

Comment: @jm666 it worked like a charm and this fancier printout is awesome! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Anyway you can recommend me a book on shell script? I'm no newbie, but most of those lines I didn't know could be done the way you did.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more efficient way to do this and it doesn't use any temporary files:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get the sorted md5sum list of all files into an array in one shot
readarray -t arr < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort)
# loop through the array and compare md5sum of contiguous items
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
  md5="${i/ */}" # extract md5sum part
  [[ "$md5" = "$prev_md5" ]] && printf '%s\n' "$prev_i" "$i"
  prev_md5="$md5"
  prev_i="$i"
done | sort -u
```

- `sort -u` is required to remove duplicates which get printed when there are more than two identical files

Comment: Anyway you can recommend me a book on shell script? I'm no newbie, but most of those lines I didn't know could be done the way you did.

Comment: @UlissesAlves - most of my recent Bash knowledge came from StackOverflow.  Mostly by watching how some experts like Charles Duffy, chepner, anubhava, barmar, Jonathan Leffler etc., answer questions.  I also look at their old answers.  Another wonderful place is the [Info tab on the Bash tag page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).